# Is it possible to assign default references to non MonoBehaviour class in Unity

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, reference, default

I have this non Monobehaviour class and I want to assign a scriptableObject reference to it. 
I can easily assign a default reference if my class would derive from Monobehaviour:
[image]
But if not it doesn't allow:
[image]
Is there a way to assign default references to a non Monobehaviour class? Or is there maybe some other workaround to this? Thank you

Comment: Do you have a reason that your class should not be a Monobehaviour ?

Comment: Well the class that needs to have a reference to a scriptableObject is derived from other class which is non-Monobehaviour. So I really do not have any choice in a matter. I've been having this issue for a while now and just don't know what is a good workaround for this type of issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use non-MonoBehaviour classes as components of your GameObject.

If you want to use SccriptableObjects in your game then create these two scripts:

```
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "MyScriptableObject")]
public class MyScriptableObject : ScriptableObject
{
    public string Data;
    //Any other data
}
```

And your Component to use this ScriptableObject

```
public class MyMonoComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MyScriptableObject Name; //Assignable in inspector
}
```

Now you can create ScriptableObjects (RMB in project foder in unity -> click MyScriptableObject) and assign it in inspector

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I'm afraid this is not an option for me. As the class that needs to hold a reference is derived from other class that is non MonoBehaviour. And this is how it needs to be for me so unfortunately this would not work.. :/

Comment: You can store the reference of your non-mono class in the `MyMonoComponent` and use it without problems